# Predict vector sequence with Keras

Tags: python, keras

Given a sequence of 995 (1,4) vectors, I want to predict the next 5 (1,4) vectors, with Keras.

My data array has shape (1000, 1000, 1, 4), which is 1000 presentations of 1000 (1,4) vectors.

I subset this data array into inputs and outputs, giving me and input array of shape (1000, 995, 1, 4) and an output array of shape (1000, 5, 1, 4).

I'm using the following code, but getting an error related to the shape of the output, and I'm unclear as to how to construct the last layer in the model to handle the output array shape.

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense 


X = np.array(test_data)[:,0:-5]
Y = np.array(test_data)[:,-5:]

print(np.shape(X))
print(np.shape(Y))

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=X.shape[1:], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))


# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model and use 10% of the data for validation
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.1)

# evaluate the model on accuracy
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

The output I recieve is an error, it seems the last layer expects the same shape as the input data `X`, rather than the output data `Y`, as seen below:

```
(1000, 995, 1, 4)
(1000, 5, 1, 4)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-ce15e7f4b527> in <module>()
     24 
     25 # Fit the model and use 10% of the data for validation
---> 26 model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.1)
     27 
     28 # evaluate the model on accuracy
```

...

```
~/Applications/miniconda3/envs/MLGA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    121                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    122                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 123                             str(data_shape))
    124     return data
    125 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_70 to have shape (995, 1, 4) but got array with shape (5, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Looking back on this, 3 years ago or so, I think I'm asking a bit much of Keras. I'll try this again by flattening the data, and it'll probably just work fine. Hopefully, I'll remember to report back.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

The issue is that the shape of the output array should be equal to the number of features in Y, i.e.,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=X.shape[1:], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
```

The X and Y can be initialized the way it was previously done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This gives me a different error:


`ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 995 input samples and 5 target samples.`

The shape of `X` and `Y` are now:

    `(995, 1000, 1, 4)`
   `(5, 1000, 1, 4)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll report back when I get a chance to test it out